# Minor css problems with li float left

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a minor css issue which I think would be quite easy for people with a bit css knowledge :)
Im doing a

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
some other content
```

And with styling:

```
ul.test {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.test li {
    float:left;
}
```

Which is straightforward. My questions is: the "some other content" always moves to the top beside the ul. It happens as soon I set the `li` to `float:left`.
How can I avoid this? Having the same behavior as if the `<li>` didnt had `float:left`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `<ul>` tag to `overflow: auto`:

```
ul.test {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Comment: Hi, this seems interesting, do you know why that overflow is needed? And isnt "auto" default value of overflow property?

Comment: I added a link with the explanation.

Comment: cool... looks so much better than using some clearing divs or something. Thanks for tip!

Answer (score 1):

When you set `float: left` on the unordered list, the rest of the content that follows, will try to align itself to the left as well (in this case to the right side of the list). To prevent this from happening, you need to clear the float. One way of doing that is as KARASZI Istvan mentioned, with setting the overflow of the list to auto. This is a trick to avoid clearing the float the "proper" way.

The proper way would be to apply the clear attribute on the content that follows.

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: left | both">    
    some other content
</div>
```

On the content that follows you can either set to clear the left float, but most people clear both floats just in case. As you see, we need to apply a style (or class) on the content that follows, and many people don't like to do it that way so there are many self-clearing tricks around.

Another popular way of "self clearing" floats is done with a "clearfix" hack. One clearfix hack is described [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple html solution is :

```
<ul class="test"><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
<br/>
some other content
```

Just using CSS, you can add   `overflow: auto`; or   `overflow: hidden`; to the `ul.test` style

I advise you the CSS solution.